# Ruby - return boolean for matching one or both elements in an array element

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, string-matching

I have an array that consists of strings with text separated by commas. I need to return a boolean that indicates if it is empty or if one or both of two other strings is the only value contained in the array element.

```
text1 = John
text2 = Doe

array1['element'] = 'John, Doe' #true
array2['element'] = 'Bob, Buck' #false
array3['element'] = 'John, Buck' #false
array4['element'] = 'John' #true
array5['element'] = 'John, John' #true
array6['element'] = '' #true
```

I can match one at a time or an empty element, but I'm not sure how to handle making sure ***only*** my matches are included and not other text.

```
foo = 'John,Doe,Buck'

    if foo['John'] 
            foo <= 'Set to Repeat'     
         elsif foo['Doe']
            foo <= 'Set to Repeat'
         elsif foo['John,Doe']
            foo <= 'Set to Repeat'
         elsif foo['']
            foo <= 'Set to Repeat'
         else foo
         end
```

Using this code I get a match, but I need to reject it because of the presence of 'Buck'.

Comment: You really should post what code you've got so far, to be really helped. Also, post examples of how you're not getting what you expect/want.

Comment: Added a rough example code snippet

Comment: I don't understand why you're comparing `foo` to `'Set to Repeat'`. The `foo[some_string]` syntax is only useful for checking if an exact substring exists, so it's not the right operation to use (You'd have to check every possible ordering!). Look into concepts like iteration, String.split, the Array operators `-` and `&`, and sets and set operations.

Comment: What is `<=` supposed to be? Do you mean "add to array"? A lot of this looks like Ruby-flavored pseudo-code, which is really not helpful. Try and put in actual code.

Comment: Your problem is in the first two lines: the two constants `John` and `Doe` are undefined, so you get a `NameError` exception.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit confusing because `array1['element']` is invalid if `array` is an array. The method [Array#[]](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D) must take one integer, two integers or a range as its argument(s). Giving it an argument that is a string will raise an exception (`TypeError (no implicit conversion of String into Integer`).

Suppose:

```
text = ['John', 'Doe']
arr = ['John,    Doe', 'Bob, Buck', 'John ,  Buck', 'John', 'John, John', '']
```

and you wish to know which elements of `arr` (strings) contain only the words in the array `text`. You can do that as follows.

```
arr.map { |s| s.split(/ *, +/).all? { |ss| text.include?(ss) } }
  #=> [true, false, false, true, true, true]
```

If, for example, `s = 'Bob, Buck'`, then

```
s.split(/, +/)
  #=> ["Bob", "Buck"]
```

Similarly,

```
'Bob'.split(/, +/)
  #=> ["Bob"] 
''.split(/, +/)
  #=> []
```

See [String#split](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-split), [Array#all?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-all-3F) and [Array#include?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-include-3F). The *regular expression* `/ *, +/` reads, "match zero or more (`*`) spaces followed by a comma followed by one or more (`+`) spaces". (If `'John,Doe'` is to be permitted use `/ *, */`.)

Alternatively, one could write

```
arr.map { |s| s.split(',').all? { |ss| text.include?(ss.strip) } }
  #=> [true, false, false, true, true, true]
```

Here

```
'John ,  Buck'.split(',')
  #=> ["John ", "  Buck"]
```

but then

```
"John ".strip
  #=> "John"
"  Buck".strip
  #=> "Buck"
```

See [String#strip](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-strip).

You may wonder why I used `Array#all?` considering that `all?`'s receiver is an array containing only two elements (e.g., `a = ['John', 'Doe']`. It is simply because it is easier to regard `a` as an array of arbitrary size than to have one statement that requires `text` to include `a[0]` and another that requires `text` to include `a[1]`.

Lastly, another variant would be to use [String#scan](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-scan):

```
arr.map { |s| s.scan(/[, ]+/).all? { |ss| text.include?(ss) } }
  #=> [true, false, false, true, true, true]
```

`scan` takes an argument that is a regular expression that reads, "match one or more (`+`) characters, each of which is a character *other than* (`^`) a comma or a space". The brackets denote a *character class*, meaning that a character must match any character in the class. The `^` at the beginning of the class definition means "other than the characters that follow".